# Make children abide by parents width

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I have a `div` nested in two `div's`. The outermost and innermost `div` has a set width. I want to make the outermost `div's` `width` to 0, so that all its children will be 0 too, or at least not visible.
But when I make the outermost `div's width` to 0, the innermost `div` is visible.

When setting the outermost `div's width` to 0, how can I make the children abide by its' parent rule?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
  small = document.getElementById('small'),
  large = document.getElementById('large');

small.addEventListener('click', function() {
  outer.style.width = 0;
});

large.addEventListener('click', function() {
  outer.style.width = '300px';
});
```

```css
#outer {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#content {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/nri7bYd.jpg");
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
#content2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="content">This is some content</div>
    <div id="content2">This is another content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="small">width = 0</button>

<button id="large">width = 300px</button>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: @Pointy Thank you! How could I have missed that! I thought there would be a simple, easy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the CSS `overflow` property to `hidden`, which clips everything outside the container.

This sort of problem has a lot of subtle variations, so different solutions are called for sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the child div with 100% width.  You are giving it a specific width (of 200px).  By setting the child to 100% you will effectively say take up as much as my parent has.

```
#content {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/nri7bYd.jpg");
    height: 200px;
    width:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9vk44jq9/